# googleapis fails ( after JWT Auth ) with TypeError: authClient.request is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-api

I am trying to access a google Sheets spreadsheet, the sheet is owned by the same account as the API Key.  I'm using JWT since there is no user present during the interaction.

Below is what I believe to be the minimal implementation to get Sheet content.

It always fails with `TypeError: authClient.request is not a function`

It would appear to me that an auth token is successfully created.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { google } = require('googleapis');

fs.readFile('./<credentials>.json','utf-8',(e,content) => {
    if ( e ) return console.log('error',e);
    authorize(JSON.parse(content))
});

function authorize(credentials) {
    let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
        credentials.client_email,
        null,
        credentials.private_key,
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']
    )
    jwtClient.authorize((e,auth) => {
        if ( e ) return console.log('authorize error',e);

        const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth });

        sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
            spreadsheetId: '<sheet_id>',
            range: 'Class Data!A1:E20',
          },(err,res) => {
              if ( err ) return console.log('SHEETS err',err);
              console.log('SHEETS res',res);
          });
    });    
};
```

The Error reported ( in full ) is consistently...

```
SHEETS err TypeError: authClient.request is not a function
    at /Users/web7/google-sheets/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js:238:31
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/web7/google-sheets/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js:19:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/web7/google-sheets/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js:15:12)
    at createAPIRequestAsync (/Users/web7/google-sheets/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js:56:12)
    at Object.createAPIRequest (/Users/web7/google-sheets/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js:48:9)
    at Resource$Spreadsheets$Values.get (/Users/web7/google-sheets/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/apis/sheets/v4.js:573:37)
    at jwtClient.authorize (/Users/web7/google-sheets/Server.js:25:36)
    at authorizeAsync.then.r (/Users/web7/google-sheets/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:117:45)
```

The Auth Token is in the form:-

```
{
 access_token: "<long_key>",
 token_type: "Bearer",
 expiry_date: 1587993215000,
 id_token: undefined,
 refresh_token: "jwt-placeholder"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- Please use `jwtClient` to `auth` like `const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth: jwtClient })`. I think that the reason of your issue might be this.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

From:

```
jwtClient.authorize((e,auth) => {
    if ( e ) return console.log('authorize error',e);

    const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth });

    sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId: '<sheet_id>',
        range: 'Class Data!A1:E20',
      },(err,res) => {
          if ( err ) return console.log('SHEETS err',err);
          console.log('SHEETS res',res);
      });
});
```

To:

```
jwtClient.authorize((err) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});
const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth: jwtClient });
sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(
  {
    spreadsheetId: '<sheet_id>',
    range: 'Class Data!A1:E20',
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log("SHEETS err", err);
    console.log("SHEETS res", res.data);
  }
);
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that you have already been got and put values for Google Spreadsheet using your service account.

Comment: The if I replace auth with auth: jwtClient I get an error `Error: The caller does not have permission`
I am not sure what is meant by 'got and put values' using my service account.  The Sheet was created directly in Google Sheets using my standard account.

Comment: @user3094755 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Can I ask you whether the Google Spreadsheet has already been shared with the email of the service account? Because in order to access to the Google Spreadsheet using the service account, the Spreadsheet is required to be shared with the email of the service account. Can you confirm it again?

Comment: The change to `auth: jwtClient` fixed the initial issue, so then it was just down to permissions and your suggestion lead me to try to share the Sheet with the email address created by Google APIs when generating the key.  ( The email send fails ), but the permission is added to the sheet, so it work now - Thanks.